# How to check if any of elements in a dictionary value is in string?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with strings and a dictionary which values are lists of strings.
I need to check if each string of the dataframe contains any element of every value in the dictionary. And if it does, I need to label it with the appropriate key from the dictionary. All I need to do is to categorize all the strings in the dataframe with keys from the dictionary.

For example.

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['x1','x2','x3','x4']})
   d = {'one':['1','aa'],'two':['2','bb']}
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({
          'a':['x1','x2','x3','x4'],
          'Category':['one','two','x3','x4']})
```

I tried this, but it has not worked:

```
   df['Category'] = np.nan
   for k, v in d.items():
       for l in v:
           df['Category'] = [k if l in str(x).lower() else x for x in df['a']]
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: I want to make sure I understand: the reason why the `a` value `x1` should have a corresponding category of `one` is because when we look at *any* of the elements of the `d['one']` list (in particular, the one that says `'1'`), we find something that *is a substring* of `x1`?

Comment: Yes, you understand it right. If any of the elements of the d['one'] list is a substring of 'x1', 'x1' gets label 'one'.

Comment: What if there is more than one label that could apply?

Comment: Then we leave the first label that suits, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly create a function that do this for you:-

```
def func(val):
    for x in range(0,len(d.values())):      
        if val in list(d.values())[x]:
            return list(d.keys())[x]
```

Now make use of `split()` and `apply()` method:-

```
df['Category']=df['a'].str.split('',expand=True)[2].apply(func)
```

Finally use `fillna()` method:-

```
df['Category']=df['Category'].fillna(df['a'])
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output:-

```
    a   Category
0   x1  one
1   x2  two
2   x3  x3
3   x4  x4
```

**Edit:**

You can also do this by:-

```
def func(val):
    for x in range(0,len(d.values())):
        if any(l in val for l in list(d.values())[x]): 
            return list(d.keys())[x]
```

then:-

```
 df['Category']=df['a'].apply(func)
```

Finally:-

```
df['Category']=df['Category'].fillna(df['a'])
```

Comment: Thank you, change your answer a little:  

    `def func(val):  
        for x in range(0,len(d.values())):  
            if any(l in val for l in list(d.values())[x]):  
                return list(d.keys())[x]  
          
    df['Category']=df['a'].apply(func)  
    df['Category']=df['Category'].fillna(df['a'])`

Comment: Edited...btw both ways works..i.e both methods give same input

Comment: Yes, in this case both methods give the same output but if input data is a little complicated the outputs are different. Thank you anyway, you helped a lot!

Comment: If this answer helped you then try considering accepting It....thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following heuristic, which looks really dirty.
It outputs what you desire, albeit with some warnings, since I've used indices to append values to dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']})
    d = {'one': ['1', 'aa'], 'two': ['2', 'bb']}
    found = False
    i = 0
    df['Category'] = np.nan
    for x in df['a']:
        for k,v in d.items():
            for item in v:
                if item in x:
                    df['Category'][i] = k
                    found = True
                    break
                else:
                    df['Category'][i] = x
            if found:
                found = False
                break
        i += 1

    print(df)


main()
```